# BoxPlot by seaborn : TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, boxplot

I am trying to plot a boxplot by seaborn, and I face the following error:

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

```
sns.boxplot(x='hour', y='flow', data=Saturday_df)
```

the dataset is:
    Saturday_df.head(2)

```
     date     time                 flow  week_day  hour

96  2016-01-02  00:00:00.000        NaN  Saturday   0
97  2016-01-02  00:15:00.000        NaN  Saturday   0
```

I faced the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```